# Flip order of elements in JSON in Python

Tags: python, json

I can't seem to find a solution for this but suppose I have JSON data:

```
data = [{"color":"blue","score":"3"},{"color":"red","score":"2"},....]
```

How do I reverse the order of color and score so it's:

```
data = [{"score":"3","color":"blue"},{"score":"2","color":"red"},....]
```

Comment: `dict` in python *has no order*. Why do you need to flip the keys anyway?

Comment: dict has no order and nobody cant you speak in which order keys right now and at the first you should sort it and when you can convert it in OrderedDict how its describes at answer section.

Comment: I thought I needed to for a certain application. It's good to know about OrderedDicts nonetheless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How I write in comment you should sort your dicts and convert them into OrderedDicts

```
from collections import OrderedDict

a = {'score':3, 'color':'red'}
b = {'score':1, 'color':'yellow'}
lst = []

for d in [a,b]:
    temp = OrderedDict()
    for k in sorted(d, reverse=True):
        temp.setdefault(k, d[k])
    lst.append(temp)

OUTPUT: [OrderedDict([('score', 3), ('color', 'red')]), OrderedDict([('score', 1), ('color', 'yellow')])]
```

Answer (score 0):

While the order of the items does not matter, if you really wanted to have a certain order you could use an [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict).

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> data = [OrderedDict([("score", "3"),("color", "blue")])]
>>> json.dumps(data)
'[{"score": "3", "color": "blue"}]'
```